# Would my application get rejected if i need to call web service in background to update the location?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, background-service

I tried reading about this in several places but i did not find anything that helped me.

For my app to work i will need to update the users location in the background AND call a web service to store some relevant information about the location. Now from what i know is that some background features only allows you to run code in the background for a specific amount of time. But not when it comes to location services and playing audio.

I am thinking about using Significant-Change Location Service so the battery drain wont be to much. Since it can work using that service why not. My question is will the app be rejected using this or is it ok to:

1. Get the users location by using significant change location service. (which i know is ok)
2. Store that information by calling a web service ( all done in the background) <--- This i dont know if it is ok to do?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it probably won't get rejected. I did something similar in the past and got approved. But keep in mind that Apple's reviewers aren't consistent about their rejections so it's impossible to be sure. They sometimes reject because of things that are perfectly ok to do according to their guidelines.

Comment: Just a little comment on this. Since the app uses significant location, then if the call to the webservice consumes little time and processor, then it is already compliant with apps that do not run in background mode. If you needed e.g. A to wait for a long time for the call to the webservice to send you some data, then you would need to enable your app for background mode and the user should accept it (I tend to say no to background mode, for example).